# Coulomb's law from Maxwell's equations.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to find general sufficient additional conditions to derive Coulomb equation for the electric field generated by a steady point charge in free space from Maxwell equations in said conditions.

I know that a way to do this is assuming that the solution of Maxwell equations must have spherical symmetry due to the disposition of charges (a single point charge infact) having such a degree of symmetry.

The thing is, how can I prove that the solution of maxwell equations has to be symmetrical if I don't know in advance the equation of the electric field? And if the answer is "because the space is isotropic", how can I mathematically write such a condition?

Infact, if I consider Maxwell's equations (I write just the first two for the case we are considering) I get

\begin{align}
\int_{\partial \Omega} E \cdot dS &= \delta(\Omega)q \\
\int_\gamma E \cdot ds =& 0 \quad \text{if} \quad \partial\gamma=\emptyset
\end{align}

($\delta$ is $1$ if the carge is inside of $\Omega$, $0$ if it is outside and $q$ is the value of the point charge) so if $E$ solves them, also $E+K$ does for every constant field $K$.

I get that space should not "choose" any direction for $K$, but how to mathematically state it? There is clearly something missing here.

I thought of adding as a condition that

\begin{equation}
\lim_{|x|\to +\infty} E = 0
\end{equation}

and this infact eliminates the possibility of adding a costant field, but I think I'm far from proving uniqueness of the solution.

Also another thing that bugged me, is the fact that it is not always the case that $\lim_{|x|\to +\infty} E = 0$, since if we impose this condition for the solution in the case of a homogeneus charged infinite plane, we don't get a solution at all.

Comment: $\operatorname{div}D = 0$ for $r>0$.

Comment: That's not sufficient since the field $E' = E + K$ where $E$ is the field given by Coulomb's equation and $K$ is any constant field, solves the equation and the additional condition.

Comment: It’s not sufficient, it’s where you start.

Comment: Are you assuming the solution to be $C^1$ except in the point where the charge is? If so how can you do it? And also  if you do then what you are proposing comes from the first equation without any trouble. Sorry but I don't understeand what you have in mind, that's shurely my fault.

Comment: I think in this case "isotropy" literally just means that the electric permittivity is constant.

Answer (score 0):

For the spherically symmetric case, you can constrain it by forcing $|E|$ to be a function of only distance $|r|$ from the point charge.

Comment: Yes but what's the general condition we have to assume (if there is) to prove that $E$ has to be spherically symmetric for this disposition of charges?

Comment: I suppose there need to be additional physical, not mathematical, constraints. For example, the physics is different under $E$ versus $E + K$. Many solutions may fit the Maxwell equation, but not all of them correspond to the physical situation being modeled.

Comment: I'm not talking about dynamics, the fact is that Maxwell's equations admit multiple solutions, so in order to rule the silly ones out we have to add a constraint, so what's the constraint?

Comment: Here are some [notes](https://www.wtamu.edu/~cbaird/SuppMaxwellUniqueness.pdf) (UMass/WTAMU) related to this subject, regarding how many constraints ME impose and boundary conditions in particular.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question because I think that maybe I've found a way to put space isotropy in mathematical therms, and infact (in this case) it solves all my problems, so I'd really like an opinion on this.

I think this could be extended with little effort to moving distributions, when I will have studied the subject in greater detail I think I will be able to update this answer.

I'm therefore assuming constitutive relation of the form:

\begin{equation}
D = D(x, E, H), \; B=B(x, E ,H), \; J = 0
\end{equation}
and the measure with sign $Q$ independent of time.

The condition I think I'm searcing is:

With $A$ being the domain (open connected) we are solving the problem in, let $f: A \to A$ of the form $f(x) = x_0 + \Lambda(x-x_0)$ bijective, where $\Lambda$ is linear and $\det(\Lambda) = \pm1$.
If $Q(\Omega) = Q(f(\Omega))$ for every $Q$-measurable set, and we have connected closed bounded 2 and 3 manifolds $\Omega$ and $S$ rispectively for wich integrals are defined, then the solution $(E,H)$ to Maxwell's equations

\begin{align}
&\oint_{\partial \Omega} D \cdot dS = Q(\Omega) \\
\oint_{\partial S}& E \cdot ds = - \frac{d}{dt} \int_S D \cdot dS \\
\frac{d}{dt}&\int_S D \cdot dS = \oint_{\partial S} H \cdot ds \\
&\oint_S D \cdot dS = 0
\end{align}

is such that $(E, H)(t,f(x)) = (\Lambda E, \Lambda B)(t,x).$

EDIT: I think I have to require also $D(f(x), \Lambda E, \Lambda H)= \Lambda D(x, E,H), \; B(f(x), \Lambda E, \Lambda H)= \Lambda B(x, E,H)$. END EDIT

For example in the case of a point charge in free space fixed in the origin, we get constitutive relations

\begin{equation}
D = \varepsilon_0 E, \; B=\mu_0H, \; J = 0
\end{equation}

and $Q(\Omega) = q\delta_0(\Omega) = q\delta_0(f(\Omega))$ whenever $f$ is a reflection or a rotation, hence with little effort we get spherical symmetry of both $E$ and $B$, and then $E(t,x)=\frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0|x|^3}x, B(t,x)=0$, as desired.

Let me know if you think this could be good.